# Accessing $1 etc. outside of string.replace() in javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

As we all know `$1` and so on are backreferences to captured groups in a string.replace() when using a regex, so you can do something like:

```
string.replace(/(http:\/\/\S*)/g, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">link<\/a>')
```

Now my question is whether there is a way to access the captured data in `$1` and so on OUTSIDE the replace. Like `backrefarray[1]` for `$1` or something...

Is such thing possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function for replacement instead of a fixed string:

```
string.replace(/(http:\/\/\S*)/g, function() {
    return '<a href="'+arguments[1]+'" target="_blank">link<\/a>';
})
```

The matches of the whole pattern and of each group are passed as arguments to the function.

Comment: Thanks, I can use this. +1 and accepted(or at least I will once the 10 minutes are over)!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use match :

```
var array = str.match(/(http:\/\/\S*)/g);
```

(but the array starts at index 0)

Comment: Nice, thanks. However Gumbo's answer is a little better for my case. +1

Answer (score 1):

### RegExp.$1

Also, after any regexp operation is finished, the `$1`, `$2` capture variables, (if they exist),  are available globally as properties of the global RegExp object. Try this out after a successful match:

```js
alert(RegExp.$1);
```